# Как определить объект, запустивший скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Куда поместить код, чтобы при нажатии кнопок на экране этот код запускался, Unity, C#. Или как по-другому определить, какая кнопка запустила выполнение скрипта из другого объекта?

```
public void UpgBuyBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  

{  
    button = ((Button)sender as Button).gameObject;  
    Name = button.transform.parent.name;  
    UpdIndex = Array.FindIndex(Upgrades, x => x.gameObject.name == Name);  
    Debug.Log(Name + "+" + UpdIndex);

    switch (button.name)  
    {  
        case "UpgBut":   
            Upg();
            break;    
        case "BuyBut":  
            BuyUpg();  
            break;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Использовать в методе `((Button) sender)` - это и есть кнопка которая была нажата

Comment: просто выведи имя gameObject'a лол

Comment: @Methorn Дело в том, что gameObject в данном случае - объект, в котором лежит этот скрипт, и это отнюдь не кнопка. Мне нужно определить именно кнопку, которая запустила скрипт

Comment: @Andrew Куда это следует поместить? (Или как заставить это включиться?) В основном сообщении код

Comment: @AlexBrand если у тебя скрипт на другом объекте висит и кнопкой ты вызываешь метод, то почему метод должен обращаться к gameObject со скриптом, а не к кнопке?

Comment: @Methorn А вот это уже не я решаю) Так сказал Unity

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью добавления аргумента Button

```
OnBuyUpg(Button button)
{
    ButtonPressed = ((Button) button as Button).gameObject;
    //остальной код
}
```